# Реализация меню как в официальном приложении Вконтакте

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

Пыталась повторить нестандартное отображения меню как в приложении Вконтакте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решила разместить контент непосредственно в `SplitView.Pane`.
На раннем этапе разместила Button и прикрутила к нему `Event` для тестирования содержимого.

```
<SplitView Name="MainSplitView"
               DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
               CompactPaneLength="48"
               PaneBackground="Gray" 
               PanePlacement="Right"
               IsPaneOpen="True">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RelativePanel Height="48">
                    <Button Name="MainSplitViewButton"
                            Height="48"
                            Width="48"
                            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                            Click="MainSplitViewButton_Click"
                            Background="Gray"
                            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                            Content="&#xE700;"/>
                </RelativePanel>
                <Frame Name="MainFrame"
                       Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="MenyFrame"/>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
```

Столкнулась с тем, что `Button` корректно не отображается в компактном режиме `SplitView`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск примеров и исходных кодов с похожей реализацией меню ничего не дал.
Вопрос к более опытным разработчикам: как в таком случае корректно произвести разметку макета, чтобы содержимое не смещалось в `SplitView.Pane`?

Comment: Не до конца понятен вопрос, приведите эскиз желаемого результата

Comment: @Андрей Постаралась нарисовать [эскиз](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8QHt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что `SplitView.Pane` не "выезжает" из-за границы экрана, как вы могли подумать, а, так сказать, "раскручивается" (ну типа как ковровая дорожка)

Немного изменил вашу разметку:

```
<SplitView Name="MainSplitView"
           DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
           CompactPaneLength="48"
           PaneBackground="Gray" 
           PanePlacement="Right"
           IsPaneOpen="True">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="MainSplitViewButton"
                        Height="48"
                        Width="48"
                        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                        Click="MainSplitViewButton_Click"
                        Background="Gray"
                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                        Content="&#xE700;"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <Frame Name="MenyFrame"/>
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Обратите внимание на добавленную строчку `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` - именно благодаря ей кнопку видно при закрытой панели. Правда при открытой панели кнопка так же справа, но как это изменить, я предлагаю вам додумать самостоятельно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень признательна за ваш ответ. Честно говоря я и не думала, что мне помогут так быстро).